# Printing an RSA private key doesn't actually return it

Tags: java, rsa

I'm trying to generate a public/private keypair to use for SSH in Java, this is just a test class to make sure I'm generating the right kind of key.

However, when I go to print the private key to console, it doesn't print the full private key.

Here's my sourcecode:

```
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;

public class Crypto
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeySpecException
    {
        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");

        keyGen.initialize(1024);

        KeyPair test = keyGen.genKeyPair();

        System.out.println(test.getPrivate());
        System.out.println(test.getPublic());
    }
}
```

I'm running Java JDK 1.7_45, this is the full console output when run within eclipse:

```
sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl@2bd00
Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: <removed because it's so long>
  public exponent: 65537
```

The string after the @ symbol keeps changing, however I don't believe it to actually be the private key.

Thanks in advance for any help guys!

**EDIT:** I'm sorry guys I didn't actually ask my question, I simply stated my problem.
My full question is: How do I access the private key as a regular String?

Comment: The String after the @ symbol is (essentially) a memory address... The PrivateKey Implementation does not appear to override `toString`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast the private key to the correct implementing type, in this case `RSAPrivateKey` (and even `RSAPrivateCrtKey`) and then extract the individual BigInteger components and format them in any way you need.

Example:

```
KeyPair test = keyGen.genKeyPair();
RSAPrivateKey priv = (RSAPrivateKey) test.getPrivate();
System.out.println(priv.getModulus());
System.out.println(priv.getPrivateExponent());
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `System.out.println();` with an object as parameter calls `toString()` on that object and returns that string. The default `toString()` implementation in [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) returns a string that looks like `"fully.qualified.ClassName@objectID"`. This is what you are seeing. It simply means that `toString()` is not overwriten in the class `sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl`.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks for the explanation. So how would I (For instance) print the full private key to file?

Answer (score 0):

To save the full private key into a file, say, `priv.pem`, try adding the following line to [Pres J K Polk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21209113/3076105)

```java
var benc = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(priv.getEncoded)));
var bpk = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
var epk = "\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
var pemk = bpk + benc.replaceAll("(.{64})", "$1\n") + epk;
var fw = new FileWriter("priv.pem");
fw.write(pemk);
fw.close();
```